# How to let a checkbox act like a radio within a parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code want to select just 1 checkbox from each `.form-group.row` - like a radio button. Each `form-group` can attend several times with each checkbox the same name. That's why I am trying a select within the specific (parent) form-group.

I know radio buttons are designed for such a thing but I work with dynamic forms.
 I've tried a lot of things, but none seems to work?

Can somebody help me please? Thank you so very much in advance!

```js
$('.form-group input').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).siblings('input').prop('checked', false);
  } else
    $('.form-group input').prop('checked', false);
});
```

```css
/* So, every "Reinigen" card has his own "Rookgasafvoer" with it's own 3 checkboxes. */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<? echo MAP_URL; ?>css/jquery-ui.min.css" />


<!-- Start Card Reinigen -->
<div class="card card-red">
  <div class="card-header">
    <strong>Reinigen</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;">Goed</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;">N.V.T</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;">Niet goed</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <label style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;">Opmerkingen:</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="verwarming_rookgas" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Rookgasafvoer:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_rookgas_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_rookgas_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="nvt" checked>
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_rookgas_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="niet-goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="verwarming_rookgas_opmerkingen[]">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="verwarming_warmtewisselaar" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Warmtewisselaar:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_warmtewisselaar_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_warmtewisselaar_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="nvt" checked>
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_warmtewisselaar_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="niet-goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="verwarming_warmtewisselaar_opmerkingen[]">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="verwarming_condensafvoer" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Condens afvoer:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_condensafvoer_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_condensafvoer_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="nvt" checked>
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_condensafvoer_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="niet-goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="verwarming_condensafvoer_opmerkingen[]">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Card Reinigen -->
<!-- Start Card Reinigen -->
<div class="card card-red">
  <div class="card-header">
    <strong>Reinigen</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;">Goed</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;">N.V.T</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;">Niet goed</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <label style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;">Opmerkingen:</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="verwarming_rookgas" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Rookgasafvoer:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_rookgas_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_rookgas_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="nvt" checked>
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_rookgas_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="niet-goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="verwarming_rookgas_opmerkingen[]">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="verwarming_warmtewisselaar" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Warmtewisselaar:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_warmtewisselaar_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_warmtewisselaar_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="nvt" checked>
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_warmtewisselaar_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="niet-goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="verwarming_warmtewisselaar_opmerkingen[]">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="verwarming_condensafvoer" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Condens afvoer:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_condensafvoer_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_condensafvoer_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="nvt" checked>
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_condensafvoer_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="niet-goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="verwarming_condensafvoer_opmerkingen[]">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Card Reinigen -->
```

Comment: Is it intended behaviour that all checkboxes in the entire form group are being unchecked whenever you uncheck any checkbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following code:

```
$('.form-group input').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest(".row").find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true)
  } else
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

When you click on a none checked checkbox it will uncheck the one that is already check and then check the one you clicked on.

**Demo**

```js
$('.form-group input').on('change', function() {
  if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).prop('checked', true)
  } else {
    $(this).closest(".row").find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true)
  }
});
```

```css
/* So, every "Reinigen" card has his own "Rookgasafvoer" with it's own 3 checkboxes. */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<? echo MAP_URL; ?>css/jquery-ui.min.css" />


<!-- Start Card Reinigen -->
<div class="card card-red">
  <div class="card-header">
    <strong>Reinigen</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;">Goed</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;">N.V.T</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;">Niet goed</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <label style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;">Opmerkingen:</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="verwarming_rookgas" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Rookgasafvoer:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_rookgas_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_rookgas_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="nvt" checked>
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_rookgas_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="niet-goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="verwarming_rookgas_opmerkingen[]">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="verwarming_warmtewisselaar" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Warmtewisselaar:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_warmtewisselaar_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_warmtewisselaar_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="nvt" checked>
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_warmtewisselaar_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="niet-goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="verwarming_warmtewisselaar_opmerkingen[]">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="verwarming_condensafvoer" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Condens afvoer:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_condensafvoer_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_condensafvoer_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="nvt" checked>
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_condensafvoer_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="niet-goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="verwarming_condensafvoer_opmerkingen[]">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Card Reinigen -->
<!-- Start Card Reinigen -->
<div class="card card-red">
  <div class="card-header">
    <strong>Reinigen</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;">Goed</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;">N.V.T</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;">Niet goed</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <label style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;">Opmerkingen:</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="verwarming_rookgas" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Rookgasafvoer:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_rookgas_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_rookgas_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="nvt" checked>
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_rookgas_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="niet-goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="verwarming_rookgas_opmerkingen[]">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="verwarming_warmtewisselaar" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Warmtewisselaar:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_warmtewisselaar_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_warmtewisselaar_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="nvt" checked>
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_warmtewisselaar_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="niet-goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="verwarming_warmtewisselaar_opmerkingen[]">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="verwarming_condensafvoer" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Condens afvoer:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_condensafvoer_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_condensafvoer_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="nvt" checked>
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_condensafvoer_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="niet-goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="verwarming_condensafvoer_opmerkingen[]">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Card Reinigen -->
```

Comment: YESSS!!! Thank you so much!!!!

Is it also possible to leave at least 1 checkbox checked?

Comment: @JoniFleischer so you must have atleast 1 checkbox in each row checked?=

Comment: Yes, that would be nice :)

Comment: @JoniFleischer try now

Comment: @JoniFleischer No problem. happy to help. If any of the answers given solved your problem, feel free to mark it as answer, inorder to help others

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to select any direct siblings of the changed checkbox that are input elements. But there are none. You have to get the siblings of the closest div and find all checkboxes inside them:

```js
$('.form-group input').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest('div').siblings().find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
  } else
    $('.form-group input').prop('checked', false);
});
```

```css
/* So, every "Reinigen" card has his own "Rookgasafvoer" with it's own 3 checkboxes. */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<? echo MAP_URL; ?>css/jquery-ui.min.css" />


<!-- Start Card Reinigen -->
<div class="card card-red">
  <div class="card-header">
    <strong>Reinigen</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;">Goed</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;">N.V.T</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;">Niet goed</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <label style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;">Opmerkingen:</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="verwarming_rookgas" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Rookgasafvoer:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_rookgas_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_rookgas_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="nvt" checked>
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_rookgas_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="niet-goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="verwarming_rookgas_opmerkingen[]">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="verwarming_warmtewisselaar" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Warmtewisselaar:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_warmtewisselaar_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_warmtewisselaar_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="nvt" checked>
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_warmtewisselaar_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="niet-goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="verwarming_warmtewisselaar_opmerkingen[]">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="verwarming_condensafvoer" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Condens afvoer:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_condensafvoer_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_condensafvoer_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="nvt" checked>
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_condensafvoer_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="niet-goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="verwarming_condensafvoer_opmerkingen[]">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Card Reinigen -->
<!-- Start Card Reinigen -->
<div class="card card-red">
  <div class="card-header">
    <strong>Reinigen</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;">Goed</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;">N.V.T</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;">Niet goed</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <label style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;">Opmerkingen:</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="verwarming_rookgas" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Rookgasafvoer:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_rookgas_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_rookgas_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="nvt" checked>
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_rookgas_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="niet-goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="verwarming_rookgas_opmerkingen[]">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="verwarming_warmtewisselaar" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Warmtewisselaar:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_warmtewisselaar_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_warmtewisselaar_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="nvt" checked>
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_warmtewisselaar_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="niet-goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="verwarming_warmtewisselaar_opmerkingen[]">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="verwarming_condensafvoer" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Condens afvoer:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_condensafvoer_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_condensafvoer_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="nvt" checked>
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 0;padding-left: 1rem;">
          <input name="verwarming_condensafvoer_status[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="niet-goed">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="verwarming_condensafvoer_opmerkingen[]">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Card Reinigen -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.form-group input').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest(".row").find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true)
  } else
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

Thanks to @[Carsten Løvbo Andersen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2943218/carsten-l%C3%B8vbo-andersen)